# GraphQL: Field Resolver Not Firing on Subscription Query?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollostack, graphql-subscriptions

I've got a subscription query, `MessageFolder_Subscription`,  that looks like this:

**QUERY**

```
const MESSAGEFOLDER_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY = gql`
    subscription ($localUserID: String!){
        MessageFolder_Subscription(userID: $localUserID){
            id
            remoteUserData{
                id
                name_title
                name_first
                name_last
                [...more fields...]
            }
        },
    }
`;
```

Here's the schema for it:

**SCHEMA**

```
type myUserData {
    id: String
    gender: String
    name_title: String
    name_first: String
    *[...more fields...]*
}

type messageFolder{
    id: String
    remoteUserData: myUserData
}

type Subscription {
    MessageFolder_Subscription(userID: String!): messageFolder
}
```

Here's how I'm doing the resolvers:

**RESOLVERS**

```
const resolvers = {
    //FIELD RESOLVER
        MessageFolder_Subscription: {
            subscribe: withFilter(
                () => pubsub.asyncIterator(MSGFOLDER_ADDED_CHANNEL),
                (payload, args) => {
                    debugger; <=== NEVER FIRES

                    if (typeof (payload) === 'undefined') {
                        return false;
                    }

                    let result = false;
                    const userId = Meteor.userId();
                     // let messageFolder = MessageFolder_Subscription.messageFolder; 
                    result = (userId === args.fromID || args === MSGFOLDERargs.toID);
                    return result;
                }
            )
        },
    //ROOT RESOLVER
        *[......more resolvers here.....]*
    Subscription: {
        MessageFolder_Subscription: {
            subscribe: withFilter(
                () => pubsub.asyncIterator(MSGFOLDER_ADDED_CHANNEL),
                (payload, args) => {
                    debugger;

                    if (typeof (payload) === 'undefined') {
                        return false;
                    }

                    let result = false;
                    const userId = Meteor.userId();
                     // let messageFolder = MessageFolder_Subscription.messageFolder; 
                    result = (userId === args.fromID || args === MSGFOLDERargs.toID);
                    return result;
                }
            )
        }
}
```

When I mutate a related item, the `MessageFolder_Subscription` query is fired by pubsub as expected. Tracing through, I can see that it returns `true`.

But for some reason, the field resolver, for the field `remoteUserData` on `MessageFolder_Subscription`, never fires.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to add the `__typename:` field:

```
const messageFolder_Subscription = {
    __typename: 'messageFolder_Subscription',
    id: userID,
}
```

...to the `MessageFolder_Subscription` subscription object, when it was created in the mutation resolver, prior to being passed to `pubsub`.